# connecting dropdowns as filters for ag grid react

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-hooks, grid, ag-grid

I have some dropdowns like so -

```
       <FilterDropdown
          title="Category"
          placeholder="Search for categories"
          options={removeDuplicatesFromArray(categories).filter( n => n)}
          selected={[]}
          onChange={() => 'test'}
        />
        <FilterDropdown
          title="Subcategory"
          placeholder="Search for subcategories"
          options={removeDuplicatesFromArray(subcategories).filter( n => n)}
          selected={[]}
          onChange={() => 'test'}
        />
        <FilterDropdown
          title="Genre"
          placeholder="Search for genres"
          options={removeDuplicatesFromArray(genres).filter(n => n)}
          selected={[]}
          onChange={() => 'test'}
        />
```

And I have an ag grid set up.
I want to link these dropdowns to ag grid so that they act as filters. When you click on values in the dropdowns, the grid instantaneously filters the data based on that.

I saw this on the ag grid documentation - https://www.ag-grid.com/react-data-grid/filter-external/

However I can't figure out if this is for what I am trying to do or not.

My grid -

```
 <Grid>
        onGridReady={onGridReady} 
        {...gridOptions} 
        quickFilterText={quickFilterText}
</Grid>
```

How can i connect my dropdowns easily to my grid? Is this possible to do client side?

The data is an array of objects. The object has many keys - category, subcategory and genre are the keys I am trying to filter on.